# Trying to read env vars into Angular 2 application

Tags: parsing, angular, environment-variables

So I am trying to set up an Angular 2 application for a prod and dev environment but the issue that I am running into is that I need it to point at separate urls as well as have a different javascript key and application id (which shouldn't be committed and should be env vars). Does anyone know how to get them to be useable by the app (client side)?

A little more info is that it is currently using lite server w/ the angular app and connecting to a Parse server (open source server) for information.